# Prove that $A ∩ (B △ C) = (A △ B) ∩ (A △ C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that for arbitrary sets $A, B, C$ the following statement is true:

$$A ∩ (B △ C) = (A △ B) ∩ (A △ C).$$

I'm familiar with the property $A ∩ (B △ C) = (A ∩ B) △ (A ∩ C)$ which seems very close to the original problem and yet I can't figure out how to solve it. I'm trying to

**Edit**: The operator $△$ is defined as $A △ B = (A \setminus B) ∪ (B \setminus A)$. I'm trying to prove the problem with any known properties of sets and axioms from set theory.

Any suggestions and ideas will be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: Am I to assume that your $\Delta$ operation is the [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference)? And what kind of proof do you want: a Venn diagram, a logical proof using inclusion and definitions of the operators, a proof from axioms that you have not given us, or something else?

Comment: Yes, the operator Δ is symmetric difference of two sets (apologies, I forgot to mention about it). I'm trying to prove the problem with any known properties of sets and axioms from set theory.

Comment: You could use a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) which calculates from the given variables $x \in A$, $x \in B$, $x \in C$ the values $x \in A \cap (BΔC)$ as well as $(AΔB) \cap (AΔC)$. (i.e. just test all 8 cases that are available.) That is not elegant at all, but nevertheless a good way to get things done when there are few cases.

Comment: This equation is not right in the first place.  Try it when A=B.

Comment: Colin, I think you are right though. I presume it's something I should have noticed earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intended identity is false. Let's use this diagram:

[image]

So $A=\{1,2,4,5\}$, $B=\{2,3,5,6\}$, and $C=\{4,5,6,7\}$. Substituting into your "identity",

$$A\cap(B\Delta C)=(A\Delta B)\cap(A\Delta C)$$
$$\{1,2,4,5\}\cap(\{2,3,5,6\}\Delta \{4,5,6,7\})
=(\{1,2,4,5\}\Delta \{2,3,5,6\})\cap(\{1,2,4,5\}\Delta \{4,5,6,7\})$$
$$\{1,2,4,5\}\cap\{2,3,4,7\}
=\{1,3,4,6\}\cap \{1,2,6,7\}$$
$$\{2,4\}=\{1,6\}$$

which is clearly false.

I would love to use a shaded Venn diagram, but I'm not sure how to do that in Geogebra. Remember, Venn diagrams are your friends! They can be used to check "identities" and to give ideas on how to prove them.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Did you intentionally use the property  A ∩ (B △ C) = (A ∩ B) △ (A ∩ C) because the actual property I'm trying to prove is A ∩ (B △ C) = (A △ B) ∩ (A △ C) ?

Comment: @e2l3n: I mistyped my answer and was correcting it before I saw your comment. I believe it is correct now: I will double-check it now.

Comment: Rory, thank you for this explanation! I agree with you and @Colin McLarty .

Answer (score 1):

Not at all, check the Venn diagrams.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Hint: $A=B$ means $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$.

Also, $A\subseteq B$ means $x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B$.

Let $x\in A\cap (B\triangle C)$.

Then $x\in A\cap (B\setminus C\cup C\setminus B)$

$x\in (A\cap B\setminus C)\cup (A\cap C\setminus B)$

$x\in ((A\cap B\setminus C)\cup A)\cap ((A\cap B\setminus C)\cup C\setminus B)$

and so on.

Comment: This is correct so far but it doesn't prove that x ∈ (A △ B) ∩ (A △ C).