# Prove that A×(B△C) = (A×B)△(A× C)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that for arbitrary sets A,B,C
the following statement is true:

**A×(B△C) = (A×B)△(A× C)**.

I can't figure out how to solve it, but △ makes me problems and I can´t get from the one side to the other side.

The operator △ is defined as A△B=(A∖B)∪(B∖A)or A△B = (A ∪ B)∖(A ∩ B) and × is cartesian product.

Any suggestions and ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). For the proof, use the ideas form [these answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147729/prove-that-a-∩-b-c-a-b-∩-a-c?noredirect=1).

Comment: Did you try to visualize it?

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align} (A \times B) \triangle (A \times C) \\&= \big((A \times B) \cup (A \times C)\big) \setminus \big((A \times B) \cap (A \times C)\big) \\&= A \times (B \cup C) \setminus A\times (B \cap C) \\&= A \times (B \triangle C).\end{align}$

Due to the property $ X \times Y = \{ (x, y) \mid x \in X, y \in Y \} $ it does not matter whether you first build the Cartesian product with the first and second set and then take the union, or if you first unionize the sets and then compute the Cartesian product. The same logic holds for the intersection.